# Why action does not executes function?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, action, xunit

I'm unit testing my validators with xUnit and there is a case when action does not executes function.

The validator is able to throw exception and and also able to populate a list containing error messages. The `shouldThroException` parameter defines when the validator should and should not throw exception. When it is not expected then it should populate errorCollection.

This test fails, because when the code gets into the else action does not calls ValidateEmailAddress, at least as I go through the code with debugger I see this. And as a consequence the errorcollection is not populated and the test fails.

How can I make it sure action calls ValidateEmailAddress?

```
[Theory]
[MemberData("StringValidatorValidateEmailAddressShouldPopulateErrorCollection")]
public void StringValidator_ValidateEmailAddress_ShouldPopulateErrorCollection(
    int order,
    string emailAddress,
    List<string> errorCollection,
    bool shouldThroException,
    int expectedAmountOfErrorsInErrorCollection)
{
    // Given

    // When
    Action action = () => this.stringValidator.ValidateEmailAddress(emailAddress, errorCollection);

    // Then
    if (shouldThroException)
    {
        action.ShouldThrowExactly<InvalidEmailAddressDigitalLibraryValidationException();
    }
    else
    {
        action.ShouldNotThrow();
    }
    errorCollection.Count.Should().Be(expectedAmountOfErrorsInErrorCollection);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> StringValidatorValidateEmailAddressShouldPopulateErrorCollection
{
    get
    {
        return new List<object[]>
        {
           new object[] { 3, "asd@c", new List<string>(), false, 1 };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why

```
action.ShouldNotThrow();
```

does not call validateEmailAddress, but I have found a workaround. If I call

```
action.ShouldNotThrowExactly<InvalidEmailAddressDigitalLibraryValidationException>();
```

Then I get the expected result.